# Uploadify is not a function v3.1

Tags: function, uploadify

Uploadify works just fine on my testing server (localhost), but once I deploy it to a remote server, it says it's not a function. I've read this may be due to the jquery library getting imported twice, but that is not the case in my situation. Everything looks identical on both servers. The only difference is that my testing server is windows and my remote server is linux.

Here is the simple test page I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.uploadify.com/wp-content/themes/uploadify/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.uploadify.com/wp-content/themes/uploadify/js/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        swf             : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        uploader        : 'uploadify/uploadify.php'
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
</body>
</html>
```

All the Uploadify files are in a folder called `uploadify`.  Thanks for the help.

EDIT

I checked out their demo page and tried linking to the .js file the same way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.uploadify.com/wp-content/themes/uploadify/js/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
```

The error has gone away, but I still can't click the button.  All I see is text that says: SELECT FILES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the directory did not even exist even though the directory and all the files were showing up in FireFTP.  I found this problem when I tried to navigate to the .js file in the uploadify folder and got an Internal Server Error 500.  When I used godaddy's FTP manager I saw that there was only one file in the uploadify folder: `.htaccess`.  I believe that file was the culprit.  I deleted it and then tried uploading all the files again.  After that it worked.